# How to create a staging table in SSIS inside Data flow task

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis

I have various data inflows from different servers. I need to populate all the data in one single destination table.

I need a staging table inside the data flow task where i can insert all the data and do some validations and then insert those data directly to destination table.

Is this possible ? Also i need to pull only the recent records based on the modified date column  of the source table. (I'm trying to create a variable that stores the date of the recent successful package execution which I can compare it with Modified date column) Is this possible ?

Let me know is there any best way to achieve above all process.

Comment: What do you mean, you "need a table inside the data flow task"?   Tables are objects in databases.   They aren't transformations in a data flow.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that it's possible to do this within one data flow task, but couldn't you use one data flow task for each stage and link them via control flow instead?

It sounds to me like the best way to do what you want is to import the data and then run a SQL task on the table with the imported data (control flow object in SSIS), it should be easy to filter the source table as you mentioned:

```
SELECT *
INTO newTable
FROM sourceTable
WHERE DateModified >= somedate
```

Hope that is useful.